# Is unused code included in a release assembly?

Tags: c#

With C# in VS2017, if I don't want to comment out a method (or class) which is not used, will it be optimized out and not included in the assembly? Or will it stay in the assembly, taking up space?

Comment: Привет [one of the only two Russian phrases I know :-) ], Arteny, I've edited your question to hopefully make it clearer. Please let me know if I've mistaken your intent.

Comment: You can check this with ILSpy or other disassembler, seeing is believing. It is in the build because the compiler doesn’t know if it is used or not

Comment: Use #if NOTDEF then.

Answer (score 5):

It is in the build because the compiler doesn’t know if it is used or not at runtime; if the assembly is a class library, it can be referenced by other assemblies, and the code can be used (if the class and method are public), so compiler will not optimize the unused code out.

You can use “#if DEBUG” and “#endif” to wrap the unused code, then it will not be compiled into the release build. DEBUG symbol is not defined in release configuration, so the compiler knows *you don’t want to* include the code in release build.

Comment: You can read more about preprocessor directives (like `#if`) here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/

Comment: You can (sometimes) get away with not using the preprocessor directives, instead using [ConditionalAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2).  It's a bit cleaner, but can only be applied to methods that have no return type.